# Siphon units in overview

Tags: eve-online

In Eve Online, do the new Mobile Structures, especially the Siphon unit, show up in the overview within the vicinity of the POS?  Are they visible to the POS owner, or do they have to be scanned down.

Answer (score 2):

They are on grid of the POS. So if the owner comes by and has his overview setup so show them he will see them. They are also scanable. So he could also just sit in one POS and scan all down other pos to avoid warping to them.

We will see how the big moon holder entitys will deal with this. Probably with some kind of intel tool where people can update moons and when they were last checked for enemy Siphons.